# Using wget\curl with prxoy list and multiple threads in bash script

Tags: curl, wget

What i am trying to do is to make a bash script on Linux, the target of the script is to take a list of url's and to download them. So i wrote a script and its works but my problem is that all the url's are come from the same website so i made a sleep for 5 min after each url and it will take a lot of time so just wanted to use proxy list so i made a script that download proxies ip's to proxy list but now what i am trying to understand what is the best way to work in this situation, i want to make a multiple threads and to download using the proxy list but to skip proxy if it can't download with it (i already check the proxy list when download them)    and to skip the file if its already downloaded it.

Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

this would work on my mac
put them in a list, we'll call it list.txt, it will have name and url
mydoc.pdf http://www.domesite/xyz/xyzdoc.pdf

```
cat list.txt | while read name url
do
curl $url > $name &
echo $! >> active.list.tmp
done


while [ $(ps -ao pid | grep -c -f  active.list.tmp) -ne 0 ]
do
sleep 1
done

echo done
rm active.list.tmp
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, but it looks like your suggestion is to make the multiple threads curl request if i got it right, but what about the proxy list? its need to download every time with different proxy and if fail to try another proxy.. The website blocks me after 10 downloads that occur without sleep for some minuets or something like this...